# Loading Previously Exported Data in amCharts5

Tags: javascript, typescript, amcharts5

Greetings,

I come seeking your invaluable expertise in the amCharts5.

Currently, I have mastered the art of exporting user-drawn lines from the chart, utilizing the powerful features of amcharts5. With a few lines of code, such as the snippet below, I am able to accomplish this feat:

```
const drawingControl = am5stock.DrawingControl.new(this.root, {
  stockChart: this.stockChart
});
const drawings = drawingControl.serializeDrawings("string", "  ");
```

But here's where I need your tech brilliance to shine! I am now on a quest to achieve the **exact opposite**: the ability to load previously exported data back into the chart. 
My goal is to ensure that the data is displayed in all its original glory, exactly as it was presented prior to being exported.

Do any of you tech maestros have any suggestions, insights, or code snippets to offer on how I can tackle this challenge? I'm eager to explore any relevant resources or techniques you might suggest.

regards,

Unfortunately, my search for a straightforward solution has yielded no fruitful results.